# Disable sun signed jars verification

Tags: jar, jvm, java-web-start

I'm getting a lot of troubles trying to publish a `.war package` containing a Web Start application with `commons-configuration-1.3.jar` in the build path `(com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException)`.

I have already tried to clean the `javaws` cache, reinstall the application, even reinstalling `java (1.6.0_24)`.

This is a stretch of my `NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610)` output while creating a `JNLP` application:

```
Warning: 
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
Signing JAR: D:\Java\workspace\OTP\DeskOTP\atual\build\cluster\modules\ext\commons-configuration-1.3.jar to D:\Java\workspace\OTP\DeskOTP\atual\build\jnlp\app\br-com-petrobras-ep-gedig-gedigdesktoplibrary\ext-commons-configuration-1.3.jar as jnlp
```

However, when trying to run I got a `JARSigningException` for this jar.

So, I decide to solve this disabling this verification. I believe I can decide and tell `jvm` not to verify my jars (my responsibility).

Is there anyway to tell `jvm` or `javaws` to NEVER verify non signed `jars`?

Comment: *"Is there anyway to tell jvm or javaws to NEVER verify non signed jars?"*  What would be the point?  Even if you can achieve it on the development machine, it is not something you should be doing on client machines.

Comment: There's a bug in some recent versions of Java where they fail to verify the certificates properly, so it would be useful to be able to bypass this for specific `.jnlp` files until the bug is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

As a first reaction, I'd say to try `java -noverify -jar your_file.jar.`

However, this will only work for local jarfiles. It will not work from a web source, which is what is sounds like you're trying to do. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I need something to ignore verifies on web. Will keep trying here. Any success will be post here. Thanks.

Comment: I did not even get this to work for local files.  I don't think the noverify option controls any of the security verifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can always download the jar from the web, manually remove the signature sections on the manifest and it should work. If the jar happens to be dynamically downloaded from the web as @Riking mentioned in the other reply, then you might be able to get around by proxying the URL to a different server.

Now, if you have access to the deployment build status and is having trouble with expired signatures on artifacts, one alternative might be to re-sign the jar using your company's (Petrobras?) signing certificates. That will allow you to work around expired issues, provided that the build knows it's supposed to pull your version of the artifact instead of the original commons-configuration.